# how to use javascript function with couchdb

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, using

I insatlled couchdb on my Windows machine. I never worked with JavaScript.

I want to use JavaScript functions to build queries. But i dont know how can i use it.

I read something with node.js but it was a bit complicate. Can somebody give me a step by step introduction ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should learn some JavaScript before diving into CouchDB View functions. There are nice online tutorials, for example http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript.

After that consult the CouchDB Guide, in particular this chapter: http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/views.html